# Removing trialing zeros from String?

Tags: java

I have a java web service which returns a list of strings type result as below.

```
12341.0
4578231.0
25.0
4785555.0
347895666.0
```

Now how can I remove trialing zeroes? what I want is list of strings as:

```
12341
4578231
25
4785555
347895666
```

how can i do it?

Comment: just zeros or remove decimal point completly...

Comment: Parse them as numbers and rebuild Strings from integers, get character arrays and process them last-to-first until there's no more trailing zeroes and rebuild the Strings from the subarray you got, there's a lot of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this is what I used using regex.

```
result = result.indexOf(".") < 0 ? result : result.replaceAll("0*$", "").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

or use Decimal Format

```
String result = "347895666.0";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
String result = decimalFormat.format(Double.valueOf(s));
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test
 {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
         Number parse = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse("12341.0");
         System.out.print(parse);
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.0+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help :

```
 string.replaceFirst("[.]0*$","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substring (Java 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or [substring (Java 8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)  method in Java.

```
String result = "12341.0";
String stripped = result.substring(0, result.indexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal format...

```
Double num= Double.parseDouble("1.300");
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(num));
```

output: 1.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting double from the web service you can use this

```
System.out.println((int)Double.parseDouble("12341.0"));
```